# Convert Date Format (04-10-2017) to (04-Oct-2017) in hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a data base the result from it for Date is in the below format

20171004

so i used this Query

```
 select SUBSTRING(week_first_day_id,1,4) ||'/' ||
 (SUBSTRING(week_first_day_id,5,2)) || '/' ||
 SUBSTRING(week_first_day_id,7,2)  from d_date;
```

the result is

```
04/10/2017
```

i want to change month format to `Mon ( 04/Oct/2017)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`date_format()`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions):

```
select date_format(week_first_day_id, 'dd/MMM/yyyy')
```

It strikes me that you are not storing the date as a date or in a standard format.  That is a bad thing, and you should fix the data.  You can parse the date and use that.  I think the code looks like:

```
select date_format(from_unix_timestamp(unix_timestamp(week_first_day_id, 'dd/mm/yyyy')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use unix_timestamp(string date, string pattern) to convert given date format to seconds passed from 1970-01-01. Then use from_unixtime() to convert to required format:

```
hive> select  from_unixtime(unix_timestamp( '20171004','yyyyMMdd'), 'dd-MMM-yyyy');
OK
_c0
04-Oct-2017
Time taken: 1.329 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```